# Regex - accept only integers and one decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that accepts only digits and one optional decimal point using:

```
const filterValue = (value) => value.replace(/^([0-9]*|\d*\.\d{1}?\d*)$/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
```

but `filterValue('test1234test')` gives me back `test1234test`.

why?

Comment: Your first pattern doesn't match non-digits, non-decimals, so they're not replaced with the empty string

Comment: Try `value.replace(/^([^.]*\.)|\.+/g, '$1').replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '')`

Comment: What can i do to keep the second pattern (`/(\..*)\./g, '$1'`) as is?

Comment: Do you wish to match `.123`, `123.` (even though they are normally written `0.123` and `123.0`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland i want to match your first 2 examples, not the second one (i don't want to allow alphabetical characters)

Comment: There's a difference between "accepting" (matching) and replacing. Your description makes it sound like you're trying to validate or match, but the code shows replacement. What output is supposed to be returned for `"test1234test"`?

Comment: @ggorlen `1234`

Comment: Why not just `s.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g)`?

Comment: @ggorlen because i want to perform a replacement like in the example i gave.

Comment: So, tried my solution?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah it is working, you can post it as an answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to keep the first dot only, and all chars other than that first dot and digits.

You may use

```
const filterValue = (value) => value.replace(/^([^.]*\.)|\.+/g, '$1').replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '')
```

**Details**

- `.replace(/^([^.]*\.)|\.+/g, '$1')`  - captures the substring from the start of the string till the first `.` into Group 1 to restore that part later with the `$1` backreference in the replacement pattern, and remove any  1+ dots anywhere else
- `.replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '')` - removes one or more occurrences of any char but digit and `.`

JS demo:

```js
const filterValue = (value) => value.replace(/^([^.]*\.)|\.+/g, '$1').replace(/[^\d.]+/g, '')
console.log(filterValue('test1234test'));
console.log(filterValue('test1.2.3.4test'));
console.log(filterValue('te.st1.2.3.4test'));
```